# List all packages from a repository

Tags: linux, command-line, apt

I have been looking how to list all packages from a repository and I couldn't find it.

For example, I add a repository (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/icons`) and I want to list all its packages (*from console*).

I want to do it in a Debian based distro.

Comment: Synaptic's nice GUI can do it...

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, but...there is no way to looking it from console with a command??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The packages list are in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`.

Check the name of the repository there.

For example, if the repository is called `ppa.launchpad.net_autostatic_doubango` then:

```
grep ^Package: /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_autostatic*_Packages
```

will give you the list.

You have to make an `apt-get update` before issuing this command to be sure that the list is updated to the latest status of the repository.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, but...there is no way to looking it from console with a command??

Comment: @bmz does this not work?

Comment: yes, this is the best solution I have at the moment.

Comment: Great answer. It may also be helpful to use `grep -h` to hide the filename in the output, then you can `sort` all the packages across the set of files.

Comment: Here's a copy and pastable command based on this answer for "everything" `find /var/lib/apt/lists/ -type f |  xargs --delimiter '\n' --max-args=1 cat | grep --text Package: | wc -l`

Comment: This answer also helped me understand what exactly `apt search` is grepping through.